# Keras Binary Model Getting stuck at 50% Accuracy

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm training a model to understand the impact of news on market volatility. The model seems to be find and the dataset classes are balanced, so I'm not sure what's exactly wrong.

I have coded a basic model using pretrained word embeddings:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size+1, embedding_dim, weights=[embedding_matrix]),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(300, return_sequences=True, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(254, activation='relu')),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
```

Training the model, I get this:

```
109/109 [==============================] - 265s 2s/step - loss: 0.6945 - 
binary_accuracy: 0.5032 - val_loss: 0.6927 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5161

109/109 [==============================] - 265s 2s/step - loss: 0.6945 - 
binary_accuracy: 0.5032 - val_loss: 0.6978 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5123

109/109 [==============================] - 265s 2s/step - loss: 0.6945 - 
binary_accuracy: 0.5032 - val_loss: 0.6859 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5096

109/109 [==============================] - 265s 2s/step - loss: 0.6945 - 
binary_accuracy: 0.5032 - val_loss: 0.6801 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5245
```

I thought maybe my issue is that the data somehow isn't related, and the model has nothing to learn, but I'm not even sure about that, actually, I have published the [dataset and the notebook on GitHub so that you can reproduce the issue, will be great if you can find what is going on.](https://github.com/dr-alberto/newsImpact)

Comment: Stick to default activations for RNNs.

Answer (score 1):

Your model seems too complex for the size of your dataset, 5,000 examples. I would suggest the following:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size+1, embedding_dim, weights=[embedding_matrix]),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, activation='relu')),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
```

Note that you have to change the output layer to 2 neurons:

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')
```

You can do it by applying `pd.get_dummies(y_train)`

Also, reduce Dropout to `0.2` and work on learning rate. Don't forget to normalize data in the interval 0 to 1:

```
def norm(x):
    return (x-np.min(x))/(np.max(x)-np.min(x))
```

Comment: Thanks for yout answer. I'm passing the one hot encoded labels through `norm()` but I'm receiving the exact same imput, nothing is changing. The input is in the range of 0 to 1, (either 0 nor 1) so I just get the same as the input.

Comment: You don't norm the labels, you already one hot encoded them. You norm features.

Comment: Alrigth, but features are labeled texts, and I'm using a word embedding with the tokenizer I used to encode the texts, so normalizing the features would make the embedding layer to don't do anything, wouldn't it? Sorry if I'm not understanding you well.

Comment: It is incorrect to use two sigmoid neurons for binary classification, only one neuron with sigmoid is needed if  using binary crossentropy loss.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy The dataset (link to GitHub repo) is trying to predict 2 variables: whether there was a move and whether the move was up or down. That may have been the reason the answer contains 2 outputs... That may still be suboptimal since it could be that when there are no more then the up/down bit makes no sense and what you need is to predict one of 3 categories: no move, move down, move up.